# Increment index of vector with some user input vector[x]++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I would like to state that I'm new to programming and really having a hard time to figure out the pattern where a user inputs few elements and pushing all those elements to a vector and increment it.

```
int n, count = 0;
std::cin >> n;
std::vector<int> vec(n);
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    vec[x]++;
    std::cout << vec[i] << std::endl;
}
```

for a sample input of 6`(n)` elements : **1 2 2 3 1 2**

The vector contains : **0 1 2 1 0 0**

It would be of a great help if anyone sheds some light to it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Now would be a good time [to learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). There are a few different techniques discussed in that article, all of them should help you understand the code you show. Of course, you need at least some *basic* understanding of arrays and vectors, and how indexes for arrays and vectors work.

Comment: Actually I'm more concerned about the list of integers in the vector, how am I getting a vector containing : 0 1 2 1 0 0

Comment: Actually, with the incomplete code you show and the input you show, the result should not be what you claim. Either your input is wrong, or your claimed output is wrong. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/),

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tested my code it works fine all I'm trying to do is understand it better and manipulate the data its returning

Comment: When [I try it](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1d073cbd5f22bcd), I get `0 2 3 1 0 0`

Comment: Can't reproduce https://wandbox.org/permlink/HQ1Tj56HfqRBupW7 Are you sure that you have also inputted the right size (6)?

Comment: @Caleth please check the code now it reproduces the exact output.

Comment: @Bob__ I'm sure that I have the correct user input

Comment: That is not the **final** content of your vector! For example, when you output the second element (vec[1]) you have changed it in first iteration, but it will be changed also later, once it is already printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words,

```
int x;
std::cin >> x;
vec[x]++;
```

You would be storing the highest frequency of the integer in an array using it as an index and incrementing the array.

Answer (score 3):

Lets take it step by step:

```
int n;std::cin>>n;
```

Input a value for the size of your vector.

```
std::vector<int> vec(n);
```

Create the vector with `n` elements, all *default initialized* which for `int` values mean they will be zero.

If you're with me this far, then the rest should be easy...

If we skip the loop:

```
int x; std::cin>>x;
vec[x]++;
```

Read a value into `x`, use that value as index into the vector, and increase the value at that index.

So if the input for `x` is `1`, then it's equivalent to `vec[1]++`, that is the second (remember that indexes are *zero based*) will be increased by one. If `vec[1]` was zero (the default from above) then it will become `1`.

With the loop, and the input `1 2 2 3 1 2`, then index `1` will be increased twice, index `2` will be increased thrice, and index `3` will be increased once. It should give you the output `0 2 3 1 0 0` (as [show here](https://ideone.com/IaYmXA)).

Answer (score 0):

You don't see "what the vector contains" at the end. You *so happen* to see an value that the vector contains during the loop, but a different input would give an output that is never the contents of the vector.

To demonstrate, we can print *the whole vector* each iteration of the loop, and we get an output like

**0** 1 0 0 0 0

0 **1** 1 0 0 0

0 1 **2** 0 0 0

0 1 2 **1** 0 0

0 2 2 1 **0** 0

0 2 3 1 0 **0**

The bolded part forms your output. Notice how the earlier terms are updated after they are printed

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<int>& vec)
{
    for (auto& el : vec)
    {
        os << el << ' ';
    }
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    int n;std::cin>>n;
    std::vector<int> vec(n);
    for(size_t i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int x; std::cin>>x;
        vec[x]++;
        std::cout << vec << std::endl;
    }
}
```

An example of an input where you don't see any of the states of the vector is

```
1 2 2 3 1 5
```

Where your output would be

```
0 1 2 1 0 1
```

Which matches none of the intermediate values

```
0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 0 
0 1 2 0 0 0 
0 1 2 1 0 0 
0 2 2 1 0 0 
0 2 2 1 0 1
```

Comment: Given that the OP is a beginner, I'd suggest replacing the templated operator overload with a simple loop.That would be more accessible to the beginner programmers that would find the question relevant and your answer helpful.

Comment: @yzt I just left it from the default [coliru program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/). And beginners need to see that templates and `<<` are not boogeymen, but useful abstractions

Comment: I believe you are wrong. Think about why there are such things as tutorials and introductory books, instead of just giving a copy of the ISO standard to every aspiring programmer and wishing them good luck.

Comment: I'm not saying to just give a copy of the standard. I *am* treating `vector` like  `basic_string` (but with a meaningful difference). I also think it is *very important* to teach **short, self contained** functions

Comment: *woosh*    Listen carefully... Do you hear it? *woosh*

Comment: Op clearly understands that `<<` and `>>` conventionally denote input and output. Their problem was with misunderstanding *what* they were outputting. Treating the *whole vector* as a value that can be output is a useful illustration. Pulling that out into it's own function is an *aid* to clarity

Comment: Is the syntax for defining streaming operators arcane? Yes. Should you never write one? No. Them's the incantations.

Answer (score -1):

What you want to do is probably to change this:

```
vec[x]++;
```

into this:

```
vec[i] = x;
```

The index of the array is in `i`, and incrementing it already happens in the `for` loop (which correctly goes one-by-one from the first element, element 0, to the last one, element n-1.)

You have to note that `x` is not the index into anything; it is the value that user wants to put into element `i` of the vector, which is reflected in the statement `vec[i] = x;`.

What you have written will cause this to happen: first, you will make a vector with `n` elements that are all initialized to 0. That's just the result of `std::vector<int> vec (n);`.

After that, the key statement is `vec[x]++;`. This is saying that for `x`, treat it as an index into the array, and increment the value of element `x` once. If effect, this counts the number of zeros, ones, twos, etc. in the input. So the result you get (0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0) is saying that you had 0 zeroes, 1 one, 2 twos, 1 three, 0 fours, and 0 fives in your list of numbers.

What do you think would happen if you had numbers greater than (or even equal to) `n` in your input? (Hint: That's what programmers call "out-of-bounds access".)

Comment: but as per the user input of 1 2 2 3 1 2 I have two 1's three 2's and one 3, I'm really having a hard time to get a hold of this can you please break it down to me; I would be forever grateful

Comment: How do you know that your code produces that output? If you post your complete program, including the output code, we might be able to help you. And, if you are looking at `vec` in a debugger, then you're probably looking at it at the wrong time.

Comment: You also might have got the input wrong. For example, if you have inputted `n` as 4, the output will match what you're seeing.

Comment: Could you please check the code now I am getting the exact output when I run the program with the defined set of user inputs mentioned above.

Comment: @Deby You're outputting the numbers as you are reading them, and that's a problem. Write a separate loop for it, after the first one is finished.

Comment: @Deby, read the other answer by Caleth to gain some insight into what your program is doing. However, I don't think their code is something you need to worry about (I'm saying that you should disregard the parts before main.)